# How can I load a texture from VBO?

Tags: c#, opentk

I already have the *.png* file in my project, and the *.png* file has the "Embedded Resource" and "Do not copy" settings.

The game runs fine - nothing throws an error, but the game does not show anything.

What did I forget, how can I load the *.png* from the VBO?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Input;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Tutorial_05
{
    class Game : GameWindow
    {
        private static int WIDTH = 1200;
        private static int HEIGHT = 720;
        private static KeyboardState keyState;

        private int vaoID;
        private int vboID;
        private int iboID;

        private Vector3[] vertices =
        {
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f), // V0
            new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), // V1
            new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), // V2
            new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f) // V3
        };

        private Vector2[] texcoords =
        {
            new Vector2(0, 0),
            new Vector2(0, 1),
            new Vector2(1, 1),
            new Vector2(1, 0)
        };

        private int[] indices = {
            0, 1, 3,
            3, 1, 2
        };

        private string vertsrc =
            @"#version 450 core

            in vec3 position;
            in vec2 textureCoords;

            out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

            void main(void)
            {
                gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
                pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
            }";

        private string fragsrc =
            @"#version 450 core

            in vec2 pass_textureCoords;

            out vec4 out_color;

            uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

            void main(void)
            {
                out_color = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords);
            }";

        private int programID;
        private int vertexShaderID;
        private int fragmentShaderID;

        private int textureID;
        private Bitmap texsrc;

        public Game() : base(WIDTH, HEIGHT, GraphicsMode.Default, "Tutorial 05 - Texturing", GameWindowFlags.Default, DisplayDevice.Default, 4, 5, GraphicsContextFlags.Default)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            CursorVisible = true;

            GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out vaoID);
            GL.BindVertexArray(vaoID);

            GL.GenBuffers(1, out vboID);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vboID);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(vertices.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.GenBuffers(1, out iboID);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, iboID);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(indices.Length * sizeof(int)), indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            vertexShaderID = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
            GL.ShaderSource(vertexShaderID, vertsrc);
            GL.CompileShader(vertexShaderID);

            fragmentShaderID = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
            GL.ShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, fragsrc);
            GL.CompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

            programID = GL.CreateProgram();
            GL.AttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
            GL.AttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
            GL.LinkProgram(programID);

            // Loading texture from embedded resource
            texsrc = new Bitmap(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Tutorial_05.example.png"));
            textureID = GL.GenTexture();

            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureID);

            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)All.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)All.Linear);

            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, texsrc.Width, texsrc.Height, 0, PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, IntPtr.Zero);

            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmap_data = texsrc.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, texsrc.Width, texsrc.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

            GL.TexSubImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, 0, 0, texsrc.Width, texsrc.Height, PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, bitmap_data.Scan0);

            texsrc.UnlockBits(bitmap_data);

            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.TextureBuffer, (IntPtr)(texcoords.Length * Vector2.SizeInBytes), texcoords, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.BindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "position");
            GL.BindAttribLocation(programID, 1, "textureCoords");
        }

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);
            GL.Viewport(0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
        }

        protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnUpdateFrame(e);
            keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Key.Escape))
            {
                Exit();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);
            // Prepare for background
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
            GL.ClearColor(Color4.Red);

            // Draw traingles
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.BindVertexArray(vaoID);
            GL.UseProgram(programID);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vboID);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture3D, textureID);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, iboID);
            GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
            GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(1);

            SwapBuffers();
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);

            GL.DeleteVertexArray(vaoID);
            GL.DeleteBuffer(vboID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be because you're binding a `Texture3D` and not a `Texture2D` in the `OnRenderFrame` method.

Also, you should probably be binding the location of your texture sampler like you are the position and texture coordinate attributes as with some drivers this is a requirement.

Finally, there is no need to call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` as it's not required with the introduction of the programmable pipeline (3.0+, I believe).